# How to set lineHeight style for TextInput in React Native?

Tags: react-native, textinput

Documentation says I can use same style for TextInput as for Text. While setting ie. lineHeight on Text has proper effect, doing so for TextInput just doesn't work.

There's no error though, which should be shown if I used not valid style property.

I'm intrested in workaround for this, even if it would require some Obj-C.

Comment: I don't have a work around for you, but I did add some detail to the issue you created. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4977

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure whether this will be fixed in 18.0-rc or 15.0-rc, but looks like Nick Lockwood fixes this in commit: [06a44a31](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/7779e06a7f2720b1fd4654c7b22b576a06a44a31). The trick is to nest a `<Text>` element inside of the `<TextInput>` element.

```
   <TextInput
     multiline={true}
     style={styles.multiline}
     onChangeText={(text) => {
       this.setState({text});
     }}
   >
     <Text>{parts}</Text>
   </TextInput>
```

Comment: This is correct solution but it implies other errors, for example there is lagging and  letter misplacement when You write fast and also line height of placeholder can't be adjusted, which looks terrible. (For now my personal solution is font with customized line height, very easy to accomplish with Font Forge)

Comment: Good to know. You should share your observations in the github commit and issue above.